# Infer domains/ranges with OWL reasoners

Tags: rdf, drools, semantic-web, owl, owl-api

How can I infer OWL domains/ranges of a given data/object property with a reasoner?

For example, I have two classes `Rat`, `Bird` and a data property `hasName`. I want these classes to be the solely domains of `hasName`:

```
<Declaration><Class IRI="#Rat"/></Declaration>
<Declaration><Class IRI="#Bird"/></Declaration>
<Declaration><DataProperty IRI="#hasName"/></Declaration>
<DataPropertyDomain>
    <DataProperty IRI="#hasName"/>
    <ObjectUnionOf>
        <Class IRI="#Rat"/>
        <Class IRI="#Bird"/>
    </ObjectUnionOf>
</DataPropertyDomain>
```

When I used HermiT reasoner to infer domain, I got the `owl:Thing` class, and not `Rat` or `Bird`:

```
Set<OWLClass> inferedDomains = hermitReasoner
                            .getDataPropertyDomains(hasNameProperty, false)
                            .getFlattened();
```

I can manually extract the domains by using owl-api to read `DataPropertyDomainAxioms` of `hasName`, to get `Rat`, `Bird` classes. But then I'll unable to get other inferable classes (e.g. `Rat` has an equivalent class `Mouse`).

So I'd like to use inference engines to infer the result, such as:

- Reasoners: HermiT, FacT++,...
- SQWRL rule engines: Drools,...

Is there any approach to achieve such results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class you've defined as domain is an anonymous one (the union of two named classes), so it cannot be returned by an implementation of `OWLReasoner`.

To work around this limitation, you can search for subclasses of the asserted domains of your property - so, using `OWLOntology::getDataPropertyDomainAxioms(OWLDataProperty)` you will retrieve the union from the root ontology; with `OWLReasoner::getSubClasses(OWLClassExpression, false)` you will be able to retrieve all nodes that contain subclasses of the disjunction. Each node will contain a set of equivalent classes; in your case, I'd expect to see a node containing `{Rat, Mouse}` and a node containing `{Bird}`.

Edit: added example to answer comments.

```
OWLOntology o = ... //root ontology for the reasoner
OWLReasoner r = ...
OWLDataProperty p = ...
for (OWLDataPropertyDomainAxiom ax: o.getDataPropertyDomainAxioms(p)) {
    OWLClassExpression c = ax.getDomain();
    NodeSet<OWLClass> allSubClasses = r.getSubClasses(c, false);
    // allSubClasses contains all named subclasses of the domain
}
```

As suggested by @AKSW in the comments, the reason why `OWLReasoner` does not return anonymous expressions in any of its methods is due to the fact that anonymous expressions in these methods are infinite: for example, given any class, there are infinite anonymous subclasses of this class. The proof is too long to be replicated here but can be easily found in description logics articles and books.

So, when `OWLReasoner` was designed, the choice was between making the reasoning incomplete (by only returning a more or less arbitrary set of anonymous expressions), undecidable (by returning an infinite set) or restrict it to named classes only. The latter was judged the best solution.

Comment: Did you mean firstly I get all property domain axioms of the property in the ontology: `OWLOntology::getDataPropertyDomainAxioms`, after that for each axiom I get all classes in the axiom's signature: `OWLDataPropertyDomainAxiom::getClassesInSignature`, then for each class I get all subclasses of the class: `OWLReasoner::getSubClasses`?

Comment: No, only the domain class - this is an anonymous class and wouldn't appear in the signature. OWLDataPropertyDomainAxiom has a dedicated method for that.

Comment: I don't know why but when I used `getClassesInSignature` it listed all subclasses of that anonymous class. which method are you talking about?

Comment: @Ignazio You should add the reason for this design decision, i.e. that the number of inferred OWL class expressions as domain would be infinite.